# Extension of survival analysis to multinomial?

Tags: survival, multinomial-distribution

Survival analysis analyzes data where the outcome variable is time until typically a binary event of interest (e.g. death, survival).  I get that and can read/learn about that.

What do you call it when you want to do a survival analysis but the event of interest is not binary anymore but multinomial ?

My event of interest has multiple states:

- death
- cure
- default
- lost-to-follow up
- complete treatment (but not cured)
- continuing treatment

While one could certainly analyze these separately, that does not make sense...  Part of the struggle is what do I call this type of analysis so I can learn about it!

Weblinks on the name/analysis would also be helpful.

Comment: multi state survival analysis eg https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf

Comment: Competing Risks Survival Analysis? [book](https://www.crcpress.com/Multivariate-Survival-Analysis-and-Competing-Risks/Crowder/p/book/9781439875216)

Comment: It looks like Multi-State is correct for my application. Thanks!